# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, when starting java program per ssh

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssh

My java program should open the default browser and open a link. When I local start the java program on my ubuntu server it works just fine, but when I start the program per ssh it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:302)
        at Server.openURL(Server.java:69)
        at Server.main(Server.java:58)
```

Maybe when starting per ssh it uses a headless version of java?
Thanks!

---

Comment: Did you use the `-X` option?

Comment: You mean "java <program> -X"? Same error

Comment: No, I mean `ssh -X hostname java -cp somepath x.y.z.Foo` Of course, you need X running on the client too

Comment: Same error. But im getting an error when starting local: Failed to load module „canberra-gtk-module“ and „WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only. Opening in existing browser session.“ But it works

Comment: That's quite a bit ask. You're hoping a remote java app is going to open the remote browser then open a link?

Comment: I sent via the client, which is on my pc, a string over socket with the link to the server, who should open it in his default browser. Code https://hastebin.com/arojoxener.swift

Comment: The first thing I'd do is to run the server and try a client from the same host

Comment: As I said, It works when I had the server and client local

Comment: Are you expecting to see the browser on the client?

Comment: No, I just should open the browser on the host

Comment: In that case you actually *don't* want `-X`. I tried to test but it refused to BROWSE when I did so

Comment: OK, just tested it again the other way around. It worked

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IVcDvuT

Comment: Other way around?

Comment: I just switched around the machines I used client-server-wise and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know now what the problem is. SSH makes a new session without a gui, even if you connected with Remote Desktop. And you cant open a browser in a session with no gui.

The solution I have is, that I connect via remote desktop to the server and open my program in the terminal. My program has now a session with gui and the browser opens.

Comment: Oh yes, you would need a gui running on the machine with the browser. But ssh doesn't really care about whether X is running (unless of course you want to forward it). As I mentioned, you don't want or need to forward X so if 'things' are OK it should works as is, as it did with me once

Comment: What do you mean with X?

Comment: X11 windowing  is what I mean

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).